# Read child nodes of variable number?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am developping a Web UI which uses a webservice that generates the following XML file:

```
<datas>
  <order>
    <order_ref>...</order_ref>
    <order_time>...</order_time>
    <products>
        <product>
          <sku>...</sku>
          <quantity>...</quantity>
          <price>...</price>
          <title>...</title>
        </product>
        <product>
          <sku>...</sku>
          <quantity>...</quantity>
          <price>...</price>
          <title>...</title>
        </product>
    </products>
  </order>
  <order>...</order>
  <order>...</order>
  <order>...</order>
  <order>...</order>
</datas>
```

As you can see, I have an XML file that contains multiple orders, that can be of variable number, as well as products in each order which are also variable in number. (e.g Order 1 has 3 products, Order 2 has 1 product, etc...)

I would like to read the attributes of products that are in a specific order.

I tried this but it returns the products from ALL orders.

```
//var orders = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("order");

var products = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("product");
for (prodIndex = 0; prodIndex  < products.length; prodIndex++) {
    document.getElementById("data"+n).innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('sku')[prodIndex].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        n++;

}
```

How do I get the products that are in orders[x]?

Comment: Loop over the orders, and then call getElementsByTagName on the specific order node to get the products beneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get deeper inside the elements "throught the tree" to the order element. In each order then find products:

```
orders = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("order");

for (i = 0; i < orders.length ;i++) {
  txt += orders[i].nodeName + ": <br>";

  prod = orders[i].getElementsByTagName("products"); 
  prods = prod[0].getElementsByTagName("product");

  for (j = 0; j < prods.length; j++){
    txt += prods[j].nodeName + "<br>";

  }

  txt += "<br>";
}
```

Additionally You should check if element exists or code won't work.

**Shortened code**

Whole ex.: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA3A1AU4NB57

```
orders = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("order");
for (i = 0; i < orders.length ;i++) {

  prods = orders[i].getElementsByTagName("products")[0].getElementsByTagName("product");

  for (j = 0; j < prods.length; j++){

    //here is Your product in prods[j] for one order "orders[i]"

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped immensely.
I linked the code to select a specific attribute
[here](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FA3D16RLJEA9)